# Spring cache with Redis using Jackson serializer: How to deal with multiple type of domain object

Tags: spring-cache, spring-data-redis

There are many types of domain objects in my web application, such as `MemberModel`, `PostModel`, `CreditsModel` and so on. I find that the type of the object is needed when configuring `JacksonJsonRedisSerializer`, so I specified `Object.class`. But I got error when deserializing objects.

To work around this, I've got 2 options:

- Use `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` instead. But the result of the serialization is too long so it will consume lots of memory in Redis.
- Configure serializer for every domian objects, which means if I have 50 domain objects then I have to configure 50 serializers. But this is obviously pretty tedious.

Is there a graceful way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an open PR [#145](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/pull/145) available. Untill that one is merged one can pretty much just implement a `RedisSerializer` the way it is done in [GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/issue/DATAREDIS-392/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/serializer/GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java) configuring the used `ObjectMapper` to inlcude type information within the json.

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);

byte[] bytes = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(domainObject);

// using Object.class allows the mapper fall back to the default typing.
// one could also use a concrete domain type if known to avoid the cast.
DomainObject target = (DomainObject) mapper.readValue(bytes, Object.class);
```